# PHP - IMAP: Save Attachment to Specific Folder

Tags: php

I found this code that works almost great but I need it to:

**1. (MUST)** Save the attachments to a specific folder on the server and not where the .php file is.

**2. (IF POSSIBLE)** Right now the code generates some files that are Zero bytes in size. (I can write something that checks the file-size and then deletes the files that are Zero in size but I would like to stop it from being created in the first place if possible.

```
 <?php

    function getFileExtension($fileName){
       $parts=explode(".",$fileName);
       return $parts[count($parts)-1];
    }

    $imap = imap_open($server, $username, $password) or die("imap connection error");
    $message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
    for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m){

        $header = imap_header($imap, $m);
        //print_r($header);

        $email[$m]['from'] = $header->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$header->from[0]->host;
        $email[$m]['fromaddress'] = $header->from[0]->personal;
        $email[$m]['to'] = $header->to[0]->mailbox;
        $email[$m]['subject'] = $header->subject;
        $email[$m]['message_id'] = $header->message_id;
        $email[$m]['date'] = $header->udate;

        $from = $email[$m]['fromaddress'];
        $from_email = $email[$m]['from'];
        $to = $email[$m]['to'];
        $subject = $email[$m]['subject'];

        echo $from_email . '</br>';
        echo $to . '</br>';
        echo $subject . '</br>';

        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $m);

        $attachments = array();
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($imap, $m, $i+1);
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
            $name = $attachment['name'];
            $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
            file_put_contents($name, $contents);
        }

        //imap_setflag_full($imap, $i, "\\Seen");
        //imap_mail_move($imap, $i, 'Trash');
    }

    imap_close($imap);

    ?>
```

Comment: From your code, i couldn't get an idea where the zero sized files are created, but I've written an answer that should help you to move the file around. Cheers

Comment: @ShobiPP to prevent 0byte file, add the `file_put_contents($name, $contents);` outside of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the file to any folder you like, The `rename()` function can be used for this purpose

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
rename('image1.jpg', 'del/image1.jpg');
```

If you want to keep the existing file in the same place you should use copy

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

```
copy('image1.jpg', 'del/image1.jpg');
```

you can use the code after you `put_file_contents()` to move the file around directories/folders

**EDIT: Create file in another directory rather than moving it around after creation**

```
file_put_contents('./myDir/myFile', $file);
```

Where the `.` represents the current directory of your project.

Also, remember `file_put_contents()` does not create folders/directories they need to be existing or you need to create it using `mkdir()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer: So as it stands now it will save into the directory where the .php files it as, is there a way to save it to a different directory without needing to move/copy/pate it ? Thanks again.

Comment: Edited answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
            $name = $attachment['name'];
            $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
            file_put_contents($name, $contents);
}
```

with

```
 foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
           file_put_contents($attachment['name'], $attachment['attachment']);
 }
```

and it will save your attachment to your root, from there you can move it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file directly on your desired path like this:

```
$mypath = '../../myfiles/';
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
           file_put_contents( $mypath . $attachment['name'], $attachment['attachment']);
 }
```