# PHP - IMAP: Save Attachment and rename it

Tags: php

I found this code under this question [PHP - IMAP: Save Attachment to Specific Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763558/php-imap-save-attachment-to-specific-folder/62002738#62002738) and it works really well. Thanks for that.

I need a little change regarding the filename. Currently the attachments will be saved with the original filename. But i need as filename the timestamp of the mail. How I need to change the code to do that?

```
<?php

    function getFileExtension($fileName){
       $parts=explode(".",$fileName);
       return $parts[count($parts)-1];
    }

    $imap = imap_open($server, $username, $password) or die("imap connection error");
    $message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
    for ($m = 1; $m <= $message_count; ++$m){

        $header = imap_header($imap, $m);
        //print_r($header);

        $email[$m]['from'] = $header->from[0]->mailbox.'@'.$header->from[0]->host;
        $email[$m]['fromaddress'] = $header->from[0]->personal;
        $email[$m]['to'] = $header->to[0]->mailbox;
        $email[$m]['subject'] = $header->subject;
        $email[$m]['message_id'] = $header->message_id;
        $email[$m]['date'] = $header->udate;

        $from = $email[$m]['fromaddress'];
        $from_email = $email[$m]['from'];
        $to = $email[$m]['to'];
        $subject = $email[$m]['subject'];

        echo $from_email . '</br>';
        echo $to . '</br>';
        echo $subject . '</br>';

        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $m);

        $attachments = array();
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) {

            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) {

                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($imap, $m, $i+1);
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) { // 3 = BASE64
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) { // 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
            $name = $attachment['name'];
            $contents = $attachment['attachment'];
            file_put_contents($name, $contents);
        }

        //imap_setflag_full($imap, $i, "\\Seen");
        //imap_mail_move($imap, $i, 'Trash');
    }

    imap_close($imap);

?>
```